# MVC ASP.NET Core 3.1 POST to Create method does not populate model

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have used Visual Studio 2019 to create a Create view (right-click > Add > View) and set the correct model when doing so.  After the Create view was created, I added code to the Create HttpPost ActionMethod and just tried to run the app.  The ActionMethod is hit, but the data model that is supposed to be passed in to the method is not populated; everything is nulls despite having entered data in the browser.  What is weird is that I have other pages in the app created the exact same way (even other Creates on other Areas) that work fine.  What am I missing?

Model:

```
   public class BondsAllProjectsModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Project Name")]
    [Required (ErrorMessage = "Project Name is required.")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Project Name Alias")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ProjectNameAlias { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Municipality { get; set; }

    [StringLength(4)]
    public string ProjectCode { get; set; }

    public bool IsProject { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*", ErrorMessage = "Only numbers are allowed.")]
    public double? ProjectAcres { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"\d+", ErrorMessage = "Only numbers are allowed.")]
    public double? ProjectUnits { get; set; }

    public int? MunicipalityID { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Project Completed must be a valid date.")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? ProjectCompleted { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string CurrentNotes { get; set; }

    public int? ProjectTypeID { get; set; }
    public bool Discontinued { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model BOnlineMVC.Models.BondsAllProjectsModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>BondsAllProjectsModel</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProjectID" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ProjectID" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProjectID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProjectName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ProjectName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProjectName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProjectNameAlias" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ProjectNameAlias" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProjectNameAlias" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Municipality" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Municipality" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Municipality" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProjectCode" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ProjectCode" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProjectCode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="IsProject" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsProject)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProjectAcres" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ProjectAcres" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProjectAcres" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProjectUnits" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ProjectUnits" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProjectUnits" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MunicipalityID" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="MunicipalityID" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MunicipalityID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProjectCompleted" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ProjectCompleted" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProjectCompleted" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CurrentNotes" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CurrentNotes" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CurrentNotes" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProjectTypeID" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ProjectTypeID" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProjectTypeID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Discontinued" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Discontinued)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(BondsAllProjectsModel projectData)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                int newProjectID = bDAL.AddProject(projectData);

                return Redirect("~/Bonds/ProjectMaintenance/Create2/" + newProjectID);
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to explicitly specify where model binder should looks when binding data by using 
`[FromForm]` attribute

[click here for more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromformattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: You come closest to what the actual problem was.  Your hint sent me back to Google which led me to this link:  [https://jonhilton.net/2017/08/17/how-to-get-data-from-an-html-form-to-your-asp.net-mvc-core-controller/].  From this article, I found that if I added the name attribute to the <input tag>, the model populated.  I have no idea why "asp-for" did not work on its own.  It seems like it should.

Answer (score 1):

top of the view   add @model namespace.BondsAllProjectsModel

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ProjectID" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.ProjectID" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ProjectID" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: This line was already there (just did not make it into the SO code block above). The data still does not populate the model.  Also, adding the asp-for=@Model.ProjectID to the <input> results in an error:  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line in the top of your create view:

`@model YourNamespace.BondsAllProjectsModel`

There is no need to modify anything else.

Comment: This line was already there (just did not make it into the SO code block above).  The data still does not populate the model.